# Android Emulator hangs and cannot quit

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have same issue as reported in [Android Emulator hang up and impossible to quit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165667/android-emulator-hang-up-and-impossible-to-quit). But the suggestion to add -noaudio does not work for me.

Cannot kill the emulator through Task manager also, and have to do a hard-reboot.

Noticed that once in a while, after reboot, I am able to kill the emulator normally. But if the PC reboots again, and try to do the same, killing emulator gives the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you attach to the hung emulator-arm process with gdb and do a backtrace you will see:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0xf77c2425 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xf777fe0c in pthread_join (threadid=3589503856, thread_return=0xffb2f84c) at pthread_join.c:89
#2  0x080eb56b in audio_pt_join (p=0x8fddb64, arg=0xffb2f87c, cap=0x82204d7 "qpa_fini_in")
    at external/qemu/audio/audio_pt_int.c:167
#3  0x080a7f1b in qpa_fini_in (hw=0x8fddaf8) at external/qemu/audio/paaudio.c:461
#4  0x0804c8cb in audio_atexit () at external/qemu/audio/audio.c:1922
#5  0xf74ef831 in __run_exit_handlers (status=0, listp=0xf7633324, run_list_atexit=true) at exit.c:78
#6  0xf74ef8bd in __GI_exit (status=0) at exit.c:100
#7  0xf74d60fb in __libc_start_main (main=0x80674b0 <main>, argc=7, ubp_av=0xffb2f9a4, 
    init=0x81e0520 <__libc_csu_init>, fini=0x81e0510 <__libc_csu_fini>, rtld_fini=0xf77d1bc0, stack_end=0xffb2f99c)
    at libc-start.c:258
#8  0x0804c1d1 in _start ()
```

This appears to be a known bug:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17294

To work around this issue, disable audio input in the AVD manager with "Audio recording support" set to "no", which sets "hw.audioInput=no" in the qemu ini file.